# Wordpress sql query update

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

hy there i want to make simple upadate form for username and biography and something is missinging and i cant update, i get blank page and when i reload nothing updates sooo this is my code on wordpress website:

```
[insert_php]
global $current_user;
global $wpdb;


$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpah_users WHERE ID=$current_user->ID");
foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
 echo "<br><br><br>";
 echo "<p>Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " .$row->wpah_users ." "."<input     type='text' id='name' Name='name'value='$row->user_nicename'/> "." </p><br>  ";
echo "<p>Biography: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " .$row->wpah_users ." "."<input  type='text' id='Biography' name='Biography' value='$row->Biography'/> "." </p><br>  ";
echo "<input type='submit' name='show' id='show' value='Upvote'>";
    echo '</form>';
}
if(isset($_POST['show'])){
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $biography=$_POST["Biography"];



$sql ="UPDATE $wpah_users
    SET ".$Biography."`= '$Biography', WHERE  `".$ID."` = '$current_user->ID'";
 $rez = $wpdb->query($sql);


 }
 [/insert_php]
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Since you're using Wordpress, look into [Data Valdiation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database)

Comment: Btw, you should hard code the column names, now the query will fail since you're trying to set the column name and value as the value of `$Biography` and `$ID` doesn't even seem to be defined

Comment: What output are you expecting from this `$row->wpah_users` statement?

Comment: ...last comment... you should redo your code. Start by doing one step at a time. First fetch the results, when that works, add the form, when that works, add the insert. Now it looks like you got invalid code in all steps.

Comment: result of $row->wpah_users is single value username and biography stored as values of textbox wich i need to update with new value

Comment: can you turn on error reporting and see what's the error?

Comment: @AnteRota if it's single value, I see no reason for using a loop.

Comment: So you got a column called `wpah_users` in a table alos called `wpah_users`?

Comment: yea kinda @MagnusEriksson

Comment: i mean i need to execute sql query on click of the button submitt and i dont know how to do that, there is no good exemple

Answer (score 0):

A number of problems.

1. The comment on `SQL injection` and `Data Validation` is not trolling, in fact...the latter is the epitome of good coding standards.
2. We are hear to help, not to aid and embed bad coding which will get you and others into a lot of trouble.
3. You are assuming your code is well written. For example, `WHERE  ".$ID."` contains an identifer '`.`', which in my knowledge php will recognize that as calling another object in side ID. Perhaps you mean that, but this is `SQL`, and you are using `Dynamic Query`. `SQL` runs by `SQL`'s rules.
4. If any columns are @variables, then they need to be validated in SQL in order to properly work. I suggest you look up [Dynamic SQL - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342(v=vs.85).aspx) to understand how SQL looks at strings and variables.
5. Use [sp_executesql - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) in your query. The query itself is not exposed to the user and it properly validates each variables such that `SQL Injection` is impossible.
6. You are treating a relational language as a cursor. Why? `SQL` is more than capable of returning your entire result set all at once. Use `SQL` as it was intended for.

Hopefully, these hints will help you find your solution.
Regards,